# How to refer to a property which is part of the ...rest in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type which is defined like this:

```
type A = {
   id: string;
}
```

And I want to allow instances of A to add optional properties, like this:

```
let options = { label: "name" };
let a: A = { id: "123", ...options };
```

Yet, this obviously creates a problem when trying to refer to the label:

```
a.label; //-> Property 'label' does not exist on type 'A'.ts(2339)
```

Since TS does allow adding destructured objects to an instance even with disregard to the type - is there a way to tell it to allow references to "optional properties", or do I have to define everything in the type definition of A ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know in advance what the property names are? If so, create a subtype of A. If not, create an indexed type or use a `Map` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an intersection `&`:

```
let options = { label: "name" };
let a: A & typeof options = { id: "123", ...options };
```

Then:

```
a.label; //Works fine.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=23&pln=14&pc=1#code/PTCSAIAsEMDcFNzXAFwJ4AdEHdIEsBjScPAZ3ABN4AzPAO3gvABs8BrRFfUgLgCg+6LOACC4ALzgA3n3By8FHuFIoATvQDmAbj4BfASBF0mEbNDopUAeyTNmV7CTorzBeOSvVR1pBSZWMFDwrOmhmcAxVAPhVIPcAGhZ2Tm5+PmZ4SwCgkPJJKRZoACN4ZiUAIlCAW3hy8F0dDMtoJTEAMlRMeE9wbODnCWkSRXBygEYAJgBmcsSAOgW+3PqdPhAATUzErjJeothggFdSZjRwAlV4aBR3JAioooyq8Fx4OlRVNE0fS+oYny4iGYxVKaWgc2BJWYWnAIAA6lZVGxyLQGHMgA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Nevertheless, allow me to please complicate this a bit and bring it closer to home with what I am actually dealing with:

If I have a factory which I pass the options too, it does not work

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=10&pln=10&pc=14#code/PTCSAIAsEMDcFNzXAFwJ4AdEHdIEsBjScPAZ3ABN4AzPAO3gvABs8BrRFfUgLgCg+6LOACC4ALzgA3n3By8FHuFIoATvQDmAbj4BfAc3gpw1aARQB7VWgngAFFJIUANOAB0H1fBXhdSqQpKKup0GroAlBIAfNKycl4oAK6qdLFy6U5KAEQADFngANROznEZHm5ePqX6+nwEFnQ+FhgoeA3kko7M0ABG8MzZdNAAtvBZujr1jcbQSmIAZKiY8BbU4M2t7bam5lZoDpngWQCMAEwAzFmu5RttjRE60G7dfcxaQA

Comment: That is because your factory takes in a variable that is of type `{id: string}`, so the type of `...rest` will always be `{}` when we exclude the property `id`. If we type it as our intersection type, then it will work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=33&pln=9&pc=45#code/PTCSAIAsEMDcFNzXAFwJ4AdEHdIEsBjScPAZ3ABN4AzPAO3gvABs8BrRFfUgLgCg+6LOACC4ALzgA3n3By8FHuFIoATvQDmAbj4BfAUMQAhCaPAAyVJngB7auBsYUeG3VI6+zeCnDVoBFBtVNFMACikSCgAacAA6eNV4FXBdJSMASgkAPmlZOUSUAFdVOly5csilACIABirwAGpIqLyK+NjE5Nb9fT4CV2THZwHTCOZoACN4Zmq6aABbeCrdHX63H2g00z8AoLRwyvAqgEYAJgBmKpj2oZc3XXSdaFjxqeYtIA

Comment: Do you just want to allow any additional properties on the object and not just what's on `typeof options`?

Comment: Thanks. Well, yeah, kind of. Because I have a lot of places where I am using this type, each with slightly different options. So referring to B in the factory signature like you did in your example is a bit of a problem. (Especially since it's in it's own file)

Comment: Okay, I revised your code to allow additional properties: playground link: `bit.ly/2ND5ccf`. One of the ways I showed works but it erases the return type, the other one is slightly more complicated but preserves the typing. Also, if this answer answered your original question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yep. now I got it. Thanks!! And here is a final link representing what I wanted to accomplish just a bit better
bit.ly/2YGzYrg